# pyro cms image loading

Tags: image, content-management-system, pyrocms

I want to display all images belong to a folder on front end using file module. I am new to pyro and I am only able to figure out how to display only one image.

```
       `{{ base_url }}/large/image_name.jpg`
```

I will have one main images folder then may sub folders which will be having images. How to get all images belong to a folder in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through the folders to create the image tags that you want.

Take a look at [Files Plugin](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/files) in the PyroCMS docs. The sample code has been provided there. You can handle conditions using tags as shown in [PyroCMS Tags](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/guides/pyrocms-tags)

Comment: i tried this :   `{{ files:listing folder="5" }}
        <img src="{{ url:site }}files/large/{{ id }}/200/150" alt="{{ description }}"/>
    {{ /files:listing }}`     it returning nothing and loop in not running. I don't know what folder="5" is but its not required so after removing it also loop is not running even once.

Comment: Also How can I use pyro CMS tags to display a database table on front end?

Comment: In folder="5", 5 is the folder id.